# Will updating `host_permissions` show warning for users?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension, manifest.json

I need to add another website (a subdomain of a current host permission) to the `host_permissions` key in the `manifest.json` file. Will doing so give users a notification to allow the changes or uninstall the extension when the update reaches them?

I'm changing the `host_permissions`, but I'm not sure what will happen when I release the changes to current users.

Comment: Yes, usually, or to be precise, expanding the area covered by host_permissions and content_scripts->matches will disable the extension.

Comment: If I don’t change the content scripts, will it? I’m just using it to fetch from the background page without Cors.

Comment: If your new host_permissions is equal to content_scripts->matches and you didn't change the latter, there should be no warning, but you can check it yourself via [getPermissionWarningsByManifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getPermissionWarningsByManifest).