# Will Chrome extension be disabled for current users if I add a new host permission to match the current content script matches?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

My understanding of adding new permissions, matches, or host permissions to your chrome extension's manifest is that it will automatically disable the extension for any current users, until they have had a chance to view and accept the new permissions (and it doesn't seem to do much to notify them, it just disables the extension).

However, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76674259/will-updating-host-permissions-show-warning-for-users) which says that if you are simply adding a host permission to include something already covered in your content script matches, that it may not trigger a new warning.

Testing with `getPermissionWarningsByManifest` seems to confirm that it does not trigger any new installation warnings, but does anyone know if it also does not auto-disable the extension?

For illustration, I would be updating this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "extension name",
    "description": "extension description.",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "tabs", "scripting"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://www.examplewebsite.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
      }
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
}
```

To this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "extension name",
    "description": "extension description.",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "tabs", "scripting"],
    "host_permissions": [
      "*://www.examplewebsite.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://www.examplewebsite.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
      }
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
}
```

I tried to look this up  but could not find a straight answer. Testing it by "load unpacked" in your own browser doesn't work bc it just auto-accepts all the permissions.

Comment: Can't you just try it and see?

Comment: @Barmar I don't want to do it if it might disable the extension for all current users.

Comment: I thought you could test it locally before posting to the web store.

Comment: @Barmar when you test locally, it just auto-accepts all the permissions no matter what they are, so this scenario never comes up. Unless their is a way to test locally that doesn't do that which I'm not aware of?

Comment: Here's the [test tool](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/permission_warnings/#update_permissions).

Comment: Great, thank you. I can confirm that it does not trigger any new warning, and after updating the actual extension, I can confirm that it does not auto-disable the extension either.